# click event not firing in Attribute directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="school in schools">
 <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
 <td>
    <span school-edit>{{school.name}}</span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

my directive

```
app.directive("school-edit",function()
{
    return {
        restrict    : "A",
        link        : function(scope,el,atr)
                    {
                        el.on("click",function()
                        {
                            alert("called");
                        });

                    }
    };
});
```

The click event is not firing 
I suppose directive is getting registered before ng-repeat populates the table

Comment: Also, try renaming your directive to schoolEdit and then in the html refer to it as the same. So, in directive schoolEdit and in html school-edit

Comment: updated my answer, please check it off if it solved your question!

Comment: Ahhmar, please marked my answer as the one you accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### working plinker http://plnkr.co/edit/XARGhQkZHgOcGZvyiD33?p=preview

OP, appears you naming convention was incorrect. avoid using dashes when defining directive. Opt for camel cased.. myDirective in the js then in the html invoke as my-directive.

Define a directive, this works by using the example I defined.

```
 app.directive('school', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      elem.bind('click', function() {

      alert("g");
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

This will do it for you.

```
<div school>click me!</div>
```

Comment: also, instead of using directive... why not attach a ng-click to the div since you're not really doing anything special with your directive that would require a directive. instantiate a function in the controller and call it to do the logic there. Directive usually are for creating html that you use over and over again, like a date picker, form submits, etc.

Comment: well i need to do some complex jquery calls here i've posted a stripped down simple version

Comment: it was a naming convention issue ,thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still looking for an answer, following would be the right way to do it (notice the difference in naming convention):

```
app.directive("schoolEdit",function()
{
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link    : function(scope,el,atr)
            {
              el.on("click",function()
              {
                 alert("called");
              });
            }
          };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is onclick.

```
app.directive("school-edit",function()
{
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        link:function(scope,el,atr)
             {
                 el.onclick = function(){
                    alert("called");
                 };
             }
    };
});
```

Comment: I just noticed that your naming is wrong. Steve has it right.